# Type Error In Actionscript 3

Tags: actionscript-3

i'm working on a flash widget. But it meet some error problem and the error is described bellow->
       1. TypeError: Error #1085: The element type "img" must be terminated by the matching end-tag "".

OK, jonathanasdf

here is my code

```
import fl.transitions.easing.*;
import fl.transitions.*;

var xml:XML;
var xmlList:XMLList;
var xmlLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader ();

var imageLoader:Loader;
var bigImage:Loader = new Loader();
var imageText:TextField = new TextField();

xmlLoader.load(new URLRequest("http://localhost/shopmajik/flash/shopdata"));

xmlLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, xmlLoaded);

function xmlLoaded(e:Event):void {
    xml=new XML (e.target.data);
    xmlList = xml.children();
    trace(xmlList);

    imageLoader = new Loader();
    imageLoader.load(new URLRequest(xmlList.elements("shopbanner").attribute("src")));
    imageLoader.x = -220;
    imageLoader.y = -187;
    addChild(imageLoader);
}
```

i've collect the data from a codeigniter controller function. I've stacked in this position if anyone please help me.

Comment: we're going to need more info than that.

Answer (score 2):

That error is due to malformed XML, your loader code is likely fine. Take a closer look at the part of your code that generates the XML and make sure it places that missing `</img>` in the right spot.

Comment: still no solution. This is my xml data in php string....

$sreturn = "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?><clients>";
$sreturn .="<client><shopbanner src='http://localhost/shopmajik/uploads/".$client->shop_banner."'>".$client->shop_banner."</shopbanner></client>"; 
  
$sreturn .= "</clients>";

Comment: please repost that code in your original post and with some proper formatting, i can't tell what's what when it's mangled like that.